# Create a pencil or sketched style in photoshop for websites

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, style

I found this image on the internet: [image: example image]

I want to use this style on some icons. Is there anyone familiar with this style and do you have an advice for me?

Comment: It may be cool to start this project on pen and paper, but scan it in and use your sketches as the images for the icons. Unless you need them to be vector, then I recommend tagging Adobe-Illustrator to your question as well.

Comment: i won't need a vector because i will use it for web only. Good idea about the pen and paper. Not sure if i have those though haha long time ago

Comment: my advice is to grab a pencil and draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull a regular icon into photoshop, then Filter -> Sketch -> Graphic Pen.

This will do your sketching look, then you probably just have to free-erase some edges, and maybe apply a light outline and you're good. Easiest way I can think of